# Tkinter button is not displayed when function is called

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
def set_language(language):
    global selected_language
    selected_language = language
    print(f"Selected language: {selected_language}")
    header.destroy()
    LeftFrame.destroy()
    create_buttons()


def choose_languages():

    header = tk.Label(root, text="Select your language", font=("Helvetica", 16))
    header.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)


    LeftFrame = tk.Label(root)
    LeftFrame.grid()
    english_button = tk.Button(LeftFrame,
                                relief="groove",
                                highlightbackground="#f2f2f2",
                                highlightcolor="#dddddd",
                                command=lambda language="EN": set_language(language))
    english_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx= 20, pady=20)
```

However when I run it using:

```
root = tk.Tk()
choose_languages()
root.mainloop()
```

My button remains empty and unclickable. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: header.grid(row=0    LeftFrame.grid(row=1)    english_button.grid(row = 2, choose_languages()
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either... I can not call a function that creates buttons.